# Divided difference relation proof using induction

Tags: numerical-methods, induction

> Given a sequence $y_0,y_1,...,$ define the forward difference operator $\Delta$ by
>   $$\Delta y_i = y_{i+1}-y_i$$
>   Powers of $\Delta$ are defined recursively by
>   $$\Delta^0y_i=y_i,$$
>   $$\Delta^jy_i=\Delta(\Delta^{j-1}y_i), \hspace{10mm} j=1,2,...$$
>   Consider a polynomial interpolation at equispaced points, $x_i=x_0+ih,  \hspace{4mm}i = 0,1,...,n$
>
> Show that 
>   $$f[x_0,x_1,...,x_j]=\frac{1}{j!h^j}\Delta^jf(x_0)$$
>   using mathematical induction

My attempt:

Checking the base case is pretty straightforward, so I will skip that. My issue is proving for $j+1$.

By using $f[x_0,....,x_j]=\frac{f[x_1,...x_j]-f[x_0,...,x_{j-1}]}{x_j-x_0}$ and rewriting using $j+1$ I get:
$$f[x_1,....,x_{j+1}]-(x_{j+1}-x_0)f[x_0,....,x_{j+1}]=f[x_0,...,x_j]$$
We assume $P(j)$ is true and we have $x_{j+1}-x_0=(j+1)h$, so we get 
$$f[x_1,....,x_{j+1}]-((j+1)h)f[x_0,....,x_{j+1}]=\frac{1}{j!h^j\Delta^jf(x_0)}$$
So I think I am on the right track here or getting close, but I am stuck on how to handle $f[x_1,....,x_{j+1}]$. My intuition is telling me that I could conclude something due to the indices being shifted by 1, but I am not quite sure what that is. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I find it useful to do the first few cases by hand. Typically, I find a pattern which applies to the general case. You should give it a try.

Comment: @CarlChristian I will give that a try. Does my work appear to be the correct direction towards the solution?